# How to extract all the -1's and 1's from a text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file that follows a pattern like this:

> train_00000.png   -1
>   train_00001.png -1
>   train_00002.png 1
>   train_00003.png 1
>   train_00004.png -1
>   train_00005.png -1
>   train_00006.png 1
>   train_00007.png 1
>   train_00008.png -1
>   train_00009.png -1
>   train_00010.png -1
>   train_00011.png 1
>   train_00012.png -1
>   train_00013.png 1
>   train_00014.png -1
>   train_00015.png -1
>   train_00016.png -1
>   train_00017.png -1
>   train_00018.png -1
>   train_00019.png -1
>   train_00020.png -1
>   train_00021.png 1
>   train_00022.png 1
>   train_00023.png -1
>   train_00024.png 1
>   train_00025.png -1
>   train_00026.png 1
>   train_00027.png 1
>   train_00028.png 1
>   train_00029.png 1
>   train_00030.png -1
>   train_00031.png 1

I am trying to extract all the -1's and 1's from this text file and then list them in an array using python. I am new to python and struggle in implementing a method to achieve this goal. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry for not making this question clear. My intent is to extract all the -1's and 1's from the text file(not the 1's contained in the image name, i.e., the 1 in "train_00001.png" should not be extracted) and put these -1's and 1's into a new array. So my output array should be [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1...]. I do apologize for the ambiguity in my original question but really appreciate your answers!

Comment: I'm a little confused -- what would the expected output be? Would it be `[-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, ...]`? Or would it be `[train_00000.png, train_00001.png, ...]`? Or something completely different?

Comment: pandas imports these kinds oft Text files in a very convenient way. You'll geht any columns you want as arrays. `import pandas as pd     df = pd.read_table(filename, sep=' ')` just habe a look at the docs, there are plenty oft keywords to adjust your import, e.g. `usecols=[0, 2]` would only import the Text columns of your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get all the file contents and loop through it with the seperation whitespaces.

```
ones = []
for i in file_con.split():
  try:
    num = int(i)
    ones.append(num)
  except:
    pass
```

This will get any entry that is a number. You can also use if statements if you just want the 1 or -1 to parse. Replace the try statement with:

```
if i == "1":
  ones.append(1)
if i == "-1":
  ones.append(-1)
```

It is also probably possible to do this with pandas, but I don't know enough to give a good solution. If you go the pandas way I suggest reading a few tutorials on it and the documentation.

Comment: the only problem I see with this solution is that the `1` from the name of the first file would also be removed

Comment: @machetazo It would not because Python only looks at the ends of the strings when stripping characters. So because it is "padded" with `.png` it will not delete any of the other characters.

Comment: @PrestonHager Thanks for your answer but I am looking for a new array that only contains -1's and 1's. Please refer to my edit and I will accept your answer if you can actually solve the problem. Sorry for my wording ambiguity!

Comment: @Steven, Ok! Check it out. I think my new edit will solve it.